# Two elements equivalent modulo a set?

Tags: group-theory, notation

I'm reading the first proof of the [orbit-stabilizer theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Orbit-Stabilizer_Theorem)  on proof wiki. I don't understand what this equation means:

$$ g \equiv h \pmod{\text{Stab} (x)}$$

Stabilizer of $x$ is a subgroup.. so what does it mean for two elements to be equal, modulo a subgroup?

Comment: What does modulo usually mean to you?

Comment: Some sort of remainder

Comment: It means $g \cdot Stab(x) = h\cdot Stab(x) $ where $g Stab(x) = \left\{ gr:r\in\text{Stab}\left(x\right)\right\} $

Comment: In algebra and number theory, modulo is usually considered a relation, not an operation. The $\pmod n$ thing is a part of $\equiv$, not an operation you apply to whatever it's on the right side of $\equiv$. That's how $5\equiv 3\pmod 2$ can make sense. If modulo were an operation, then it would make statements like $5\equiv3\pmod 2$ problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means there exists an element $s$ of ${\rm Stab}(x)$ such that $g=hs$. That's if the left cosets are considered; otherwise, it's $g=sh$.

Comment: Are you sure it's not that there is an element such that $g=sh$?

Comment: I'm not sure, @Arthur. That's a good question. Thank you.

Comment: I suppose it depends on whether one is considering left or right cosets of ${\rm Stab}(x)$.

Comment: From the linked page, it's apparent it's talking about left cosets, but the notation itself is ugly when it's not a normal subgroup...

Comment: @BrianMoehring I would very much have preferred $g\operatorname{Stab}(x)=h\operatorname{Stab}(x)$, yes. Or the alternative offered in this answer. Modding or quotienting by a non-normal subgroup is highly non-conventional.

Comment: I don't understand, @Buraian. Because $s\in{\rm Stab}(x)$ seems to answer your question . . .

Comment: Oops stab(x) is in G only. My bad